# Adding Xamarin.Google.iOS.SignIn results in a native linking error (MT5209)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I wanted to replace the Google.Plus library from an existing app with the Xamarin.Google.iOS.SignIn library using the Google Sign-In for iOS component (https://components.xamarin.com/view/googleiossignin).

However... when adding it and replacing the old code with the new (slightly different code) it results in a compile error:

```
/projectdir/MTOUCH: Error MT5209: Native linking error: file not found: /projectdir/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/mtouch-cache/libOpenInChrome.a (MT5209) (Immo.Vlan.Touch)
/projectdir/MTOUCH: Error MT5202: Native linking failed. Please review the build log. (MT5202) (Immo.Vlan.Touch)
```

Here is the relevant part from the build log:

```
MTOUCH:  warning MT1302: Could not extract the native library 'libOpenInChrome.a' from '/projectdir/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/mtouch-cache/libOpenInChrome.a'. Please ensure the native library was properly embedded in the managed assembly (if the assembly was built using a binding project, the native library must be included in the project, and its Build Action must be 'ObjcBindingNativeLibrary').
MTOUCH:  warning MT1302: Could not extract the native library 'libGTMOAuth2_external.a' from '/projectdir/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/mtouch-cache/libGTMOAuth2_external.a'. Please ensure the native library was properly embedded in the managed assembly (if the assembly was built using a binding project, the native library must be included in the project, and its Build Action must be 'ObjcBindingNativeLibrary').
MTOUCH:  warning MT1302: Could not extract the native library 'libGTMOAuth2_internal.a' from '/projectdir/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/mtouch-cache/libGTMOAuth2_internal.a'. Please ensure the native library was properly embedded in the managed assembly (if the assembly was built using a binding project, the native library must be included in the project, and its Build Action must be 'ObjcBindingNativeLibrary').
MTOUCH:  warning MT1302: Could not extract the native library 'libSignIn.a' from '/projectdir/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/mtouch-cache/libSignIn.a'. Please ensure the native library was properly embedded in the managed assembly (if the assembly was built using a binding project, the native library must be included in the project, and its Build Action must be 'ObjcBindingNativeLibrary').
MTOUCH:  warning MT1302: Could not extract the native library 'libGIPNSURL+FIFE.a' from '/projectdir/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/mtouch-cache/libGIPNSURL+FIFE.a'. Please ensure the native library was properly embedded in the managed assembly (if the assembly was built using a binding project, the native library must be included in the project, and its Build Action must be 'ObjcBindingNativeLibrary').
MTOUCH:  warning MT1302: Could not extract the native library 'libGTM_AddressBook.a' from '/projectdir/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/mtouch-cache/libGTM_AddressBook.a'. Please ensure the native library was properly embedded in the managed assembly (if the assembly was built using a binding project, the native library must be included in the project, and its Build Action must be 'ObjcBindingNativeLibrary').
MTOUCH:  warning MT1302: Could not extract the native library 'libGTM_core.a' from '/projectdir/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/mtouch-cache/libGTM_core.a'. Please ensure the native library was properly embedded in the managed assembly (if the assembly was built using a binding project, the native library must be included in the project, and its Build Action must be 'ObjcBindingNativeLibrary').
MTOUCH:  warning MT1302: Could not extract the native library 'libGTM_DebugUtils.a' from '/projectdir/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/mtouch-cache/libGTM_DebugUtils.a'. Please ensure the native library was properly embedded in the managed assembly (if the assembly was built using a binding project, the native library must be included in the project, and its Build Action must be 'ObjcBindingNativeLibrary').
MTOUCH:  warning MT1302: Could not extract the native library 'libGTM_GTMURLBuilder.a' from '/projectdir/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/mtouch-cache/libGTM_GTMURLBuilder.a'. Please ensure the native library was properly embedded in the managed assembly (if the assembly was built using a binding project, the native library must be included in the project, and its Build Action must be 'ObjcBindingNativeLibrary').
MTOUCH:  warning MT1302: Could not extract the native library 'libGTM_iPhone.a' from '/projectdir/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/mtouch-cache/libGTM_iPhone.a'. Please ensure the native library was properly embedded in the managed assembly (if the assembly was built using a binding project, the native library must be included in the project, and its Build Action must be 'ObjcBindingNativeLibrary').
MTOUCH:  warning MT1302: Could not extract the native library 'libGTM_KVO.a' from '/projectdir/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/mtouch-cache/libGTM_KVO.a'. Please ensure the native library was properly embedded in the managed assembly (if the assembly was built using a binding project, the native library must be included in the project, and its Build Action must be 'ObjcBindingNativeLibrary').
MTOUCH:  warning MT1302: Could not extract the native library 'libGTM_NSData+zlib.a' from '/projectdir/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/mtouch-cache/libGTM_NSData+zlib.a'. Please ensure the native library was properly embedded in the managed assembly (if the assembly was built using a binding project, the native library must be included in the project, and its Build Action must be 'ObjcBindingNativeLibrary').
MTOUCH:  warning MT1302: Could not extract the native library 'libGTM_NSDictionary+URLArguments.a' from '/projectdir/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/mtouch-cache/libGTM_NSDictionary+URLArguments.a'. Please ensure the native library was properly embedded in the managed assembly (if the assembly was built using a binding project, the native library must be included in the project, and its Build Action must be 'ObjcBindingNativeLibrary').
```

Any suggestions on how to tackle this?

Niels

Comment: FWIW I'm having the same problem, but I got the package from NuGet. Xamarin.Google.iOS.Core and SignIn.

Comment: i'm having a similar issue using an updated version of Google Analytics. I also got it from NuGet. Any updates? Find a solution yet?

Answer (score 2):

These dlls no longer have the native libraries embedded.  The addition of the native libraries is now handled in an additional build task that is added to the app project when the NuGet is added to the app project.

Be sure to add the [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Google.iOS.SignIn/) or Component to the app project as well.

Some are experiencing the problem when the Microsoft.Bcl.Build NuGet is added to the project as well.  We intend to release a patch for this issue soon.  Look for version 0.2.1 of the `Xamarin.Build.Download` NuGet.

To work around the issue you will need to edit the targets file `packages/Xamarin.Build.Download.0.2.0/build/Xamarin.Build.Download.targets`

Add a `AfterTargets="AssignProjectConfiguration"` attribute to the `_XamarinBuildDownload` target.

```xml
<Target
    Name="_XamarinBuildDownload"
    DependsOnTargets="_XamarinBuildDownloadCore;_XamarinBuildAddDownloadedItems"
    AfterTargets="AssignProjectConfiguration"
    Condition="'@(XamarinBuildDownload)'!=''"
    />
```

Comment: I am seeing this same error with Google Analytics iOS. Do you know if this is a similar issue? I already added the NuGet Component.
MTOUCH:  warning MT1302: Could not extract the native library 'libGoogleAnalytics.a' from '/Debug/mtouch-cache/libGoogleAnalytics.a'. Please ensure the native library was properly embedded in the managed assembly (if the assembly was built using a binding project, the native library must be included in the project, and its Build Action must be 'ObjcBindingNativeLibrary').

Comment: I believe that it is related.  Are you certain that you added the NuGet to the app project and not just a library project that the app project references?

Comment: I went to Project > Add NuGet packages... and added the Google API's Analytics iOS Library

Comment: Thanks.  We must be missing something.  You can track or add additional comments on our forms thread.  Once we get answers there I will update my answer here.  https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/185738

Comment: Thanks. I've been following that thread too. I've tried to reply, but my posts aren't showing up for some reason. my csproj file does have those import build statements fwiw.

Comment: I tried the latest suggestion of "Add a AfterTargets="AssignProjectConfiguration" attribute to the _XamarinBuildDownload target." in the other thread but it is still not working for me with Google Analytics. 

Most of my posts in the other thread are not showing up, I'm not sure why.

Comment: @holmes in 0.4.7 also this AfterTargets="AssignProjectConfiguration" is missing. however adding it manually works.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the same problem with Google Analytics on Xamarin iOS installing `Xamarin.Build.Download 0.2.2-beta1`

I hope this will become as soon as possible the stable version.

Comment: It's 2020, having same problem. I just downgraded to 0.2.2 and then it started working !!

Answer (score 0):

After additional research I think the problem is that the native libraries referenced are not included in the DLL. If I open the DLL for the current version of Google.Core (`v1.3.2.1`) there's no `Resources` entry. If I open `v1.1.0beta-3` I can see a resources entry that contains all the libraries referenced.

So solution is to have them rebuild it properly.

I'm not 100% confident that this is the answer. For some reason my project will compile fine on simulator but not on device. But the fact that it's referencing the missing names I think is very suggestive.

Comment: Simulator builds are more forgiving as the full linker pass is not run.  This allows you to have missing symbols at build time.  But if you attempt to call these symbols at runtime the app will throw an exception.